# how to use 6 radio buttons to display diffrent pictures each and show a little discripion in the south border when pressed

Tags: java

this is blank this is blank this is blank this is blank this is blank this is blank this is blank this is blank this is blank this is blank this is blank 
this is blank this is blank this is blank this is blank this is blank this is blank this is blank this is blank this is blank this is blank this is blank

Comment: But what is your question? This code works, effect is not spectacular, but it does what you want. So what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your code to create this GUI:

[image: Image Display]

Here are the major changes I made:

1. I created an ImageInformation class to hold the image, title, and description.  Whenever you find yourself listing several variables, think about creating a getter / setter class.
2. I started the Java Swing application with a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  **This is critical.**  You must start a Swing application on the Event Dispatch thread (EDT).  By calling the invokeLater method, you are ensuring that the Swing application starts on the EDT.
3. I read the image(s) before I did anything else.  You read the images into your Swing application once, and use them.
4. I created a List of ImageInformation.  From this List, I could initialize the Swing GUI, and react to the radio button clicks in the Item Listener.
5. I rearranged your code to put like things together.  This becomes more important as your code gets larger.  It makes it easier to find things when the code is together.

Here's your code with my changes.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class ImageDisplay implements Runnable {

    private ItemListener listener;

    private JFrame frame;

    private JLabel titleLabel;
    private JLabel imageLabel;
    private JLabel descriptionLabel;

    private List<ImageInformation> images;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ImageDisplay());
    }

    public ImageDisplay() {
        this.images = setImageInformation();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Image Display");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel();
        imagePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        ImageInformation defaultImageInformation = images.get(0);

        titleLabel = new JLabel(defaultImageInformation.getTitle());
        titleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        imagePanel.add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
                defaultImageInformation.getImage()));
        imagePanel.add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        descriptionLabel = new JLabel(defaultImageInformation.getDescription());
        descriptionLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        imagePanel.add(descriptionLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.add(createControlPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createControlPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Images"));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

        listener = new ImageListener();

        for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
            ImageInformation imageInformation = images.get(i);
            JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton(imageInformation.getTitle());
            if (i == 0) {
                button.setSelected(true);
            }
            button.addItemListener(listener);
            group.add(button);
            panel.add(button);
        }

        return panel;
    }

    private List<ImageInformation> setImageInformation() {
        List<ImageInformation> images = new ArrayList<ImageInformation>();

        // Here, you would get your images
        Image image = getImage("StockMarket.png");

        images.add(new ImageInformation(image, "Image 1", "Image 1 Description"));
        images.add(new ImageInformation(image, "Image 2", "Image 2 Description"));
        images.add(new ImageInformation(image, "Image 3", "Image 3 Description"));
        images.add(new ImageInformation(image, "Image 4", "Image 4 Description"));
        images.add(new ImageInformation(image, "Image 5", "Image 5 Description"));
        images.add(new ImageInformation(image, "Image 6", "Image 6 Description"));

        return images;
    }

    private Image getImage(String fileName) {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private ImageInformation getImageInformation(String title) {
        for (ImageInformation imageInformation : images) {
            if (title.equals(imageInformation.getTitle())) {
                return imageInformation;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public class ImageListener implements ItemListener {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
            if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                JRadioButton button = (JRadioButton) event.getItem();
                String labelText = button.getText();
                ImageInformation imageInformation = getImageInformation(labelText);
                if (imageInformation != null) {
                    titleLabel.setText(imageInformation.getTitle());
                    imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imageInformation
                            .getImage()));
                    descriptionLabel.setText(imageInformation.getDescription());
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class ImageInformation {

        private final Image image;

        private final String title;
        private final String description;

        public ImageInformation(Image image, String title, String description) {
            this.image = image;
            this.title = title;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public Image getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

    }
}
```